# Antivirus shows an error when I use scanf function

Tags: c, scanf

I am learning C, but whenever I run a program I get this error:

```
a.exe failed to run: Access is denied 
+CategoryInfo: Resources Unavailable:(:) [], Application failed exception 
+ Fully qualified error is : nativecommandfailed
```

This error is because of McAfee (real-time scanning) but I don't know how to stop it.

I think it's asking me to put input when I use the `scanf()` function but it shows an error.

Comment: You should post a sample program, for instance does this program yield the same error: `int main() { return 0; }`.  If the program is good then it's a system issue with McAfee or whatever.

Comment: My AV seems to arbitrarily block some of my little test programs, and after that I can never use the same path name for the test program. So I excluded that folder from the AV. Sometimes they detect a "signature" that happens to match a known virus.

Comment: @AllanWind yes code runs when I run above code ,    sir please advise me what I do.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and share a program that doesn't work for you.  @WeatherVane is probably right, but that's not a programming question, but something to ask McAfee or failing that Superuser about.

Comment: @AllanWind "My code when compiled doesn't run" is certainly a ["specific programming problem" that is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not if it's the anti-virus program that prevents any random program from running (IMHO).  That's an application configuration issue.

Comment: I simply uninstall McAfee and the code runs successfully...

Answer (score -1):

I think your antivirus software, McAfee, is preventing the execution of the .exe file for security purposes. Could you try disabling this feature? Additionally, please ensure that you have installed the C compiler for running your code in Visual Studio.

Comment: This does not answer the question and is only asking clarifying questions. It should have been posted as a comment instead. Once you gain enough reputation, you will be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) asking for clarifying information.